# Zend Framework - don't have permission to access file in public

Tags: zend-framework

That is my iframe:

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" class="igm" src="/flash/dewplayer-vol.xml&
amp;container=enterprise&amp;view=default&amp;lang=en&amp;country=ALL&amp;sanitize=0&
amp;v=cb90d5949f2275bc&amp;up_CCOL=%23d1dae3&amp;up_START=No&
amp;up_MP3=http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?video_id=z0FERtqhwHs&
h=6a29a4973a0431d2638ba3f5a1aecfeb&r=1373776845504&amp;up_LOOP=No&
amp;libs=analytics:core:flash&amp;mid=55&amp;rpctoken=-1666220716119396559" 
frameborder="0" height="400" scrolling="yes" width="500"></iframe>
```

But when I open my page it appears:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /flash/dewplayer-vol.xml&container=enterprise&view=default&lang=en&country=ALL&sanitize=0&v=cb90d5949f2275bc&up_CCOL=#d1dae3&up_START=No&up_MP3=http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6 Server at 212.43.43.254 Port 80

That is my httpd.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot C:\AppServ\www\site\public
 </VirtualHost>

<Directory "C:/AppServ/www/site/public">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There some several step you have to follow in web server just go throw all this

**1.** Find the `httpd.conf` file (usually you will find it in a folder called conf, config or something along those lines)

**2.** Inside the `httpd.conf` file uncomment the line LoadModule rewrite_module `modules/mod_rewrite.so` (remove the pound '#' sign from in front of the line)

Also find the line ClearModuleList is uncommented then find and make sure that the line AddModule mod_rewrite.c is not commented out.

And still you have more query then go to this [LINK](http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Apache-Tutorial-Enable-Mod_rewrite-Windows_t11623.html)

Also

If you set up your virtual host the default way, i.e.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "D:/Users/user/www/yourwebsite.dev/public"
   ServerName .local

   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

   <Directory "D:/Users/user/www/yourwebsite.dev/public">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

You may access the public dir, by:

http://yourwebsite.dev/
and files in public dir by:

http://yourwebsite.dev/filename.ext

**It is all about DocumentRoot.**

i hope this will sure help you.

Comment: pls change slash for DocumentRoot C:\AppServ\www\site\public

Comment: I change slash for DocumentRoot but don't have result

Comment: Have you restart your server ?

Comment: Yes, i restart my server